# drupal: logged in status message?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

when an user login in Drupal, the login block disappear from my pages.

I would like instead to keep it there with a message stating the user is logged in.

Something like this (with logout link): "Welcome Patrick. Logout"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login-form will not work for not logged in-users.

What is easiest, is to make a new block (admin » build » blocks » new(tab)) 
Then set that block to show only for role "authenticated". That way, the block will work exact opposite from the user-login block, which shows only for role: anonymous.

You can add any custom text in there, as long as it is static text. If you want to include dynamic text, such as "Hello $username, you will have to go for the tip by Jeremy French: create a module with its own hook_block.

Answer (score 0):

The login block is created by the follwing code from the [user_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_block/6) function.

```
    if (!$user->uid && !(arg(0) == 'user' && !is_numeric(arg(1)))) {
      $block['subject'] = t('User login');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
    }
```

There is no code to display a message if you are logged in.

One simple way to do what you want would be to create a module which implements the above code in hook_block, and has an elese statement which displays what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve your problem, is to create a new block with whatever you want in it, and only show it when the user is logged in. If you arrange the placement and style, it will look like the same block, even though they are different.

You can create the new block with a custom module or views.